# I can't figure out syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, import

Why do I have a sytax error on line 21? (at the if($sql) line) I am new to this and cannot figure it out.  I have been spinning my wheels for an hour. I'm sure its something very simple for most people on here.

```
 <?php 
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("solera_menu",$conn);

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

        $handle = fopen($file,"r");
        while(($fileop = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",")) !==false)
        {
            $order = $fileop[0];
            $category = $fileop[1];
            $name = $fileop[2];
            $description = $fileop[3];
            $price = $fileop[4];


            $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO dinner (order,category,name,description,price) VALUES ('$order','$category','$name','$description','$price')")

            if($sql)
            {
                echo 'Data Uploaded Successfully';
            }
        }

    }

?>
```

Comment: Missing `;` at the end of the `$sql =...` line

Comment: Take a look at `mysqli` or `PDO`. `mysql_*` is deprecated ;)

Comment: Wow, I'm stupid! Thanks Mark.  I knew it was something simple!!

Comment: It always helps if you actually say what the error message actually is, not simply what line it's at

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No semicolon after `mysql_query()`.

If you're just importing a CSV file, try the [`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html) statement, or its command-line interface [mysqlimport](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlimport.html).

This is likely to be 10-20x faster than the method you're using.

It'll also prevent the SQL injection vulnerability you've created with your current code.

Here's a rough example, though I have not tested it:

```
<?php 
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("solera_menu",$conn);

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $status = mysql_query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$file' INTO TABLE dinner");

        if($status)
        {
            echo 'Data Uploaded Successfully';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: The code doesn't work.  Notice: Undefined variable: sql in C:\wamp\www\soleramenu\upload.php on line 10

Comment: Sorry, I missed an edit.  Changes $sql to $status.  Note also that I have not tested this, and I'm making some necessary assumptions about your CSV file and your "dinner" table.